# ¿como llamar a ventana modal con jquery en PHP?

Tags: php, jquery

tengo el siguiente código en PHP y estoy haciendo una tabla donde muestra los registro de mi base de datos, tengo un boton para editar y otro para eliminar pero cuando llamo la ventana modal para eliminar el registro no muestra nada, ni siquiera sale algún mensaje de error, no me muestra la ventana modal que debería de mostrar donde pregunta si deseo eliminar el registro, no se que esta mal.

```
<?php

require 'conexion.php';

$where ="";

$SQL = "SELECT * FROM personas";
$Resul = $mysqli->query($SQL);

?>

<html lang="es">

<head>


<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap-theme.css">
<script type="text/javascript" scr="js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" scr="js/jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" scr="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <h2 style="text-align:center">Curso de PHP</h2>

        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <a href="nuevo.php" class="btn btn-primary">Nuevo Registro</a>
        </div>
   <br>
   <!-- Creamos una tabla responsiva -->
   <div class="row table-responsive">
<table class="table table-striped">
    <thead> <!-- Encabezado de la tabla -->
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Nombre</th>
            <th>Email</th>
            <th>Telefono</th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
   <tbody> 
        <?php while($row = $Resul->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) { ?>
        <tr>

            <td> <?php echo $row['id']; ?></td>
            <td> <?php echo $row['nombre']; ?></td>
            <td> <?php echo $row['correo']; ?></td>
            <td> <?php echo $row['telefono']; ?></td>
            <td> <a href="modificar.php?id=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>"><span 
    class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span></a> </td>
            <td><a href="#" data-href="eliminar.php?id=<?php echo 
    $row['id']; ?>" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#confirm-delete"><span 
   class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span></a></td></tr>
        <?php } ?>
    </tbody> 
  </table>
  </div>

 </div>

            <!-- Modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="confirm-delete" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" 
    aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">

                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" 
   aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Eliminar 
  Registro</h4>
                </div>

                <div class="modal-body">
                    ¿Desea eliminar este registro?
                </div>

                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-
      dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                    <a class="btn btn-danger btn-ok">Delete</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!--Scrip en Jquery-->
    <script>
        $('#confirm-delete').on('show.bs.modal', function(e) {
            $(this).find('.btn-ok').attr('href', 
    $(e.relatedTarget).data('href'));

            $('.debug-url').html('Delete URL: <strong>' + 
    $(this).find('.btn-ok').attr('href') + '</strong>');
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: ¿Has proado a usar document ready? https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/ - https://api.jquery.com/ready/

Comment: Estás agregando jQuery dos veces en tu página y las dos de manera local

Answer (score 0):

Si tienes que llamar una modal desde PHP, algo no has hecho bien en tu planteamiento. Pero poder puedes. La idea es generar el código javascript o jQuery que llamaría la ventana modal en una variable de PHP definida previamente como empty, luego dentro del body, si la variable contiene código, la pintas, sería algo así:

```
<?php

    $modal = "";

    if($algo) {
        $modal = "$('#modal').show();";
    }

?>

<body>
    <script>
        <?php
            if(!empty($modal)) {
                echo $modal;
            }
        ?>
    </script>
</body>
```

Como PHP se ejecuta antes de entregar al cliente, el código final quedará con el show de la modal si $algo se cumple.

Answer (score 0):

Gracias, el inconveniente que tenia era porque estaba usando una version diferente de Jquery, he descargado el proyecto de ejemplo que estaba utilizando y estoy trabajando con la version de Jquery que esta incluida y ya funciona el modal, Gracias

Comment: Hola CeciliaMa, ¿qué versiones son las que te dieron problemas de compatibilidad?